# How to download a xls file from Rails route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3, xls

In my AngularJS application, I'm calling a route (from a Rails application) that returns me the contents of a xls file (like below):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Ecpm</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Total Revenue</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
      .
      .
      .
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">4.9</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1587.25</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

The controller's method is like

```
def medias_served_export
  @medias_served = query_medias_served_export_by_context('Site')
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.xls { send_data @medias_served, filename: 'teste.xls', disposition: 'attachment', type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' }
  end
end
```

The URL is like **/api/statistics/earnings/medias_served_export/20171001/20171030.xls**

How can I download the file instead of just receive all the text? Should the backend set extra Headers in the route's method?

Comment: Have you tried `send_file` in your controller action?

Comment: set appropriate excel mime header. Browsers won't load excel and will force download

Comment: I've updated the question with the controller's code. Both the mimeType and the send_file instructions are correct?